# Cant get email validation working in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, validation, email

Hey guys am having a bit of problems with my jQuery, I have all the input validations all working, but I cant get my REGEX code working for validating my email. tried entering "hello@mywebsite.co.uk" my personal email and my work email and all of them dont work.

Any help is highly appriciated.

```
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  $('.submitbutton').click(function () {
    if ($("input.name").val() == '') {
        alert("Name is a required field");
        return false;
    }
    else if ($("input.email").val() == '') {
        alert("Email is a required field");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!regex.test("input.email")) {
        alert("This is not a valid email address");
        return false;
    }
    else if ($("textarea.message").val() == '') {
        alert("Message is a required field");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Cheers

Comment: Check this out http://ask.altervista.org/demo/jquery-validate-e-mail-address-regex/

Comment: Consider updating your regex. The following valid addresses will not be matched by your regex: john@server.department.company.com , local@sub.domains.com, etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `regex.test("input.email")`, you're testing if the actual string `"input.email"` is matching the regex. Instead, you should test the *value* of `input.email` element.

So use:

```
regex.test($("input.email").val())
```